# Activity instance is null sometimes even after onCreate

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have a strange crash that I see happening from time to time.

the crash is :

```
Non-fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com....../com......MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.FragmentManager com........MainActivity.getFragmentManager()' on a null object reference
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity
```

the backstrace of the crash is :

```
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException
com.......adapters.MyRecyclerViewAdapter.<init> 
com.......fragments.MyFragment.onCreate
android.app.Fragment.performCreate (Fragment.java:2242)
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate (AppCompatActivity.java:84)
com.........MainActivity.onCreate (MainActivity.java:223)
android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6876)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Now the code is:
inside Activity's onCreate I use :

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mActivity = this;
        ....
        ....
    }
```

and then:

```
public static MainActivity getInstance() {
        return mActivity;
    }
```

Then I open the fragment MyFragment:

```
mFragmentManager
.beginTransaction()
.addToBackStack("some key")
.add(R.id.container,
        MyFragment.getFragment( ... ),
        MyFragment.TAG).commit();
```

and inside the fragment I initialize a RecyclerView Adapter. 
Now inside the adapter's contructor the crash happens in the line :

```
MainActivity.getInstance().getFragmentManager();
```

which means the activity is somehow null, but how is it possible if we'd just seen in the backtrace that the activity's onCreate was called and that the MyFragment was added to backstack of this activity ?

Comment: please add complete class code if possible

Comment: Does your Activity extend `FragmentActivity` or `Activity`?

Comment: @H.Brooks it extends AppCompatActivity

Comment: Try using `getSupportFragmentManager` instead of `getFragmentManager`

Answer (score 0):

Replace code

```
getActivity().getFragmentManager();
```

in place of

```
MainActivity.getInstance().getFragmentManager();
```

Hope this will work